# How to open a sliding window?

Tags: design, actuator

I live in an apartment that has sliding windows in it. The apartment is naturally warm because we live above a mechanical room, such that we either opened the windows or ran the air conditioning through the winter. I want to create a device than can open and close the windows in the apartment depending on temperature. The software and electronics are already figured out, I just need to figure out how to move the windows.

[image]

This is a sample of the window. It takes about 4 lbs of force to pull it open, and they only open 6 inches(since I'm 16 stories high).

Ultimately, I want to make this cheap enough that I could replicate it on 6 windows.

My first thought was a linear actuator, but most of the ones I have seen are designed for moving 100+lbs and cost several hundred dollars. Pneumatic actuators are cheaper, but I'd have to run a network of air lines and solenoids, and would have a compressor that would randomly kick in. A double winch system would be very complicated to set up and prone to failure. Lastly, I was thinking of a cheap metal gear servo(dealextreme has 15kg/cm servos for under $15.00), but it would be somewhat difficult to use a series of turnbuckles and arms to translate into 6 inches of linear movement.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If speed is not crucial, there's also the screw!

Comment: Yes... You can get a cheap screw in any hardware store and build a linear actuator.  That's common for hobby CNC work...

Comment: you mind linking to what you mean by `screw`

Answer (score 7):

As others have said in comments, a screw is probably your best bet. It's mechanically pretty simple to set up, and could be made to look fairly tidy, which is always nice in a home.

But the main problem, as always is going to be doing this on the cheap. The cost of the parts soon adds up. Even if your motors are only $15, you still need to buy the lead screw and nuts. These can be shockingly expensive if you buy nice ones for CNC machines, but you can probably get away with a simple length of threaded rod attached to a motor mounted on the wall, and a nut attached to the window. Since this thing isn't going to be moving very often, it should last a reasonably long time. And when the components wear out, they'll be cheap to replace.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:
Using wire cable; mount pulleys at each corner of window; then get a suitable motor for your pull requirement (4lbs). wind the cable around the motor shatft then power forward/backward to Maybe use a block and tackle arrangement for increased torque. Don't forget the need for limit stop switches.

This could be cheaper than screw method but might not have same look and feel

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be cheap....you could go to a junk yard and grab a linear actuator used for opening and closing car door windows.

Comment: These aren't usually linear actuators, although the mechanism creates linear movement: http://www.bestcarsguide.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/Window-Regulator.jpg